# Group counts. Why every column?

Tags: python, pandas

I often need to know how many entries I have in each group in a dataframe in Pandas. The following does it, but it returns one value for every column in my dataframe.

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C']).count()
```

That is, if I have, say `20` columns (where `A`, `B` and `C` are three of them), it would return `17` counts, all identical (at least every time I have done it) within each group.

1. What is the rationale behind this?
2. Is there any way to restrict the count to only one column? (or have it return only one value per group?)
3. Would that speed up the counts in any way?

The method `dataFrameGroupBy.count` doesn't seem to have an argument to specify on which columns to do the count (I also could not find it on the [API ref](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#id6))

Comment: Re #2:  You can select column D with this syntax:  `df.groupby('A')['D'].count()`.  Strangely I can't find that in the standard documentation but here's an old blog post (look near the middle):  http://wesmckinney.com/blog/?p=125

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby(...).count()` returns the count of *non null* values in each column. So potentially it can be different for each column.

example:

```
>>> df
   jim  joe  jolie
0    4  NaN      4
1    8    0    NaN
>>> df.groupby('jim').count()
     joe  jolie
jim            
4      0      1
8      1      0
```

`.groupby(...).size()` returns the `size` of each group.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. I think what I need is `size()`. It would still be nice to be able to specify the column for `count`. Perhaps is in the works. I will see if I can do a PR on that.